# Printing out results from the database which are after the current date

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm creating a web page which has events with different dates which are printed out from my database using php. I want it so the events which have gone past the current date automatically do not show on the page.

I'm using the 'date' type in mySQLi for holding the date and when i'm inserting the date into my database i'm using the code;

```
<?php

if($db_server){

$eventdate = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['eventdate']);

$timeDate = strtotime($eventdate);

$tempdate = date("Y-m-d", $timeDate); 

$query = "INSERT INTO events (eventdate) VALUES ('$tempdate')";

mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or 

die("Insert failed. ". mysqli_error($db_server));

$message = "Event Uploaded";  

 }else{ 

       $message = "Error: could not connect to the database."; 

} 

?>

Event Date: <input type="event-upload"  class="standard" name="eventdate" id="datepicker" />
```

Here's the code when i'm printing out the date;

```
<?php

if($db_server){

$query = "SELECT * FROM events"; 

$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db_server)); 

if (!$result) die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($db_server)); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

          echo $row['eventdate']
}

}

?>
```

If someone could help me out it and tell me what the right WHERE clause is to use, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Need to display the past event or current event ?

Comment: All events which are AFTER the current date

Comment: AFTER the current date mean future event

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventdate >= '".date("Y-m-d")."'";
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: is this only selecting the events which have the current date though? I want all of the events to appear which are after the current date?

Comment: That selects all events on or after the current date.  That's what the >= means.

Comment: OK thanks yes that's what I want, although I've just run the code and all of the results still appear, even if they are before the current date?

Answer (score 0):

Use this using DATEDIFF function in mysql

```
select * from `events` where DATEDIFF(`eventdate`,now() ) > 0
```

Comment: It's really odd, this has no effect when i run the code, all of the results still appear, even if they are before the current date.

Comment: If your date is stored as Y-m-d then the above should work 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff